# Server throwing 500 error on certain route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been doing some small school project on making our own API and connecting it to an angular front end.

I've been following guide on things and I've came across the problem where my app started throwing internal server error 500 after implementing controllers.

It all worked fine until I've imported the controllers for user registration.
Posts controller works just fine, so does the login part of the ap

I tried logging the errors but it wouldnt output anything.

Here is my code:

user route

```
const express = require("express");

const UserController = require("../controllers/user");

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/signup", UserController.createUser);

router.post("/login", UserController.userLogin);

module.exports = router;
```

User controller

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const User = require("../models/user");

exports.createUser = (req, res, next) => {
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10).then(hash => {
    const user = new User({
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hash
    });
    user
      .save()
      .then(result => {
        res.status(201).json({
          message: "User created!",
          result: result
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
          message: "Invalid authentication credentials!"
        });
      });
  });
}

exports.userLogin = (req, res, next) => {
  let fetchedUser;
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      }
      fetchedUser = user;
      return bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    })
    .then(result => {
      if (!result) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      }
      const token = jwt.sign(
        { email: fetchedUser.email, userId: fetchedUser._id },
        "b9SNz3xg9gjY",
        { expiresIn: "1h" }
      );
      res.status(200).json({
        token: token,
        expiresIn: 3600,
        userId: fetchedUser._id
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: "Invalid authentication credentials!"
      });
    });
}
```

I am expecting to be able to register an account which will be able to post new posts. It all worked just fine until I've made controllers and moved the requests and functions into controller file.

I really apologize for asking this probably simple question, but my programming skills are still low

Comment: can you provide your index.js file where you apply exported router to express middleware? BTW what is a content of an error?

Comment: a stack trace should come with the internal server error. It would contain the answer to your problem.

Comment: @majidarif it only shows that XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:3000/api/user/signup".

Comment: @pepega I hope you didn't share your actual mongodb username and password in the hastebin link above. If so, please remove it as soon as possible.

Comment: @SudhanshuVishnoi oh my god, thanks

Comment: @l2ysho  here is my index file https://hastebin.com/abuqubigor.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `userLogin`, when the `user` doesn't exist, you return `res.status(401)...`, which is chained to the next `.then` call as `result` (instead of your expectation that it would be the value returned by `bcrypt.compare`).

What you can do is instead of:

```
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      message: "Auth failed"
    });
  }
```

try

```
  if (!user) {
    throw new Error("Auth failed");
  }
```

which will be caught in your `.catch`.

Comment: Login works just fine, only problem is creating user

Comment: Please share the stack trace of error on the server.

Comment: This is the only output I get in the console of dev tools.
https://imgur.com/a/IJjcurI

Comment: I mean in your terminal running the server code.
Also, if you go the the network panel of devtools and see the response for the URL you showed above, I think the error stack trace might be visible there too.

Comment: Congrats and all the best 